# Need Suggestions for IE11 SCRIPT1010 Error

Tags: typescript, babeljs, internet-explorer-11, office-js, polyfills

I'm developing an Office Web Add-In using the Office-JS package. The add-in functions as expected on Mac, but fails to load on Windows. The add-in renders using a Safari based webview on Mac, but an IE11 based webview on Windows, which I believe is the root of the issue.

I don't actually know if this is related at all to the Office-JS package and webview enviornment, but I'm mentioning it just for context.

I'm not able to get much debugging information from the Microsoft Office Webivew, but when I load the URL of the  of the application in IE11 I get the following error in the console:

`SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier`

It lists the JS file where the error is encountered. The exact character is the `{` before `isClean` in the following line: `...,e,r){"use strict";let n,i,o,s=r("dUwI"),{isClean:a}=r("zomH"),u=r("aOxJ"),c=r("wWcZ")`

I'm using webpack and here is part of the configuration that I think might be most relevant.

```
    entry: {
      polyfill: ['core-js/stable', 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'],
      vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'core-js'],
      taskpane: ['react-hot-loader/patch', './src/taskpane/index.tsx'],
    },
```

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "lib": ["es7", "dom"],
    "pretty": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

Here's my babel.config.json:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-typescript"]
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to even begin debugging?

Answer (score 0):

> The exact character is the { before isClean
> `{isClean:a}=r("zomH")`

This is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) used for object destructuring with renaming.

IE11 doesn't support any flavour of destructuring assignment. Try [@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-destructuring).